# How to serve yaml file with sinatra? (not download)

Tags: ruby, yaml, sinatra, rack

I have a basic Sinatra app, I'd like to serve a `yaml` file so that it can be read by a gem via http.

I'm just able to download it:

```
get '/download' do
  send_file './en.yml', :filename => 'en.yml', :type => 'text/yaml'
end
```

But how can I just serve it without downloading?

Goal is that a gem makes an http request to obtain the content of this endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't convert the YAML to JSON and serve that?

```
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/json' # from sinatra-contrib
require 'yaml'

get '/download' do
  json YAML.safe_load(File.read('en.yml'))
end
```

Comment: no reason, I've just work always with Rails apis, serving json, images, html files. I just wanted to learn if there were a way to give a yml response. Json response is fine, I'll parse it in the client then. Thanks!

Comment: the reason is actually, I am using the i18n gem, so I want to pass to the `I18n.load_path` method a file served via http (yaml format), that's why I needed it yaml. Not sure how to pass translations to the i18n that are not in a file

Comment: so one solution I thought is getting the yaml file, and then I just need to load it from temp folder. That's why I need the server to return a yaml file and not a json object